# Why is wordpress trying to re-install itself?

Tags: database, installation

I ran out of space on my MySQL server so I got a bigger disk and moved the files to the new disk, restarted MySQL and things were fine. But I went to my sites and now wordpress is acting like its never been installed before, its taking me through the install and setup like it was a brand new site. It was working fine yesterday. I dont get it.

Comment: Check database server details in `wp-config.php` and confirm these are ok. Also did you moved database too on new disk.

Comment: Yes I moved the database to a new disk. All the configs are correct.

Comment: didn't you answer yourself that it was a issue with mysql user permission?